# Search files in project folder dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my Windows Store project I have some .jpg files in my Assets folder. How can I dynamically get all the .jpg files from that folder?

I've tried:

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ms-appx:///Assets/");
var fileList = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery);
```

Must work somehow like this (with a different CommonFileQuery) but this is not working for me. (System Exception at line 1 - wrong path name).

Second question: how do I test if my Assets folder contains "movie.mp4"?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to use storagefolder? You could use Directory.GetFiles() to get all files by a specific search pattern.

Comment: The Directory class is not supported in a Windows Store project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete solution for my scenario:

1. Get Files within a project folder of a certain file type.
2. Check if a file exists within a project folder.

1:

```
StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

StorageFolder subFolder = await installedLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
subFolder = await subFolder.GetFolderAsync("Images");

List<String> fileType = new List<String>();
fileType.Add(".jpg");
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, fileType);
var query = subFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

var fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
```

2:

```
try
{
  var video = await subFolder.GetFileAsync("Video.mp4");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("No Video found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>You can use Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);</del>

Question 2:

You can use File.Exists(filePath);

**Edit**
As per your comment, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) which uses `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` instead of `GetFolderFromPathAsync`

or

```
StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var files = installedLocation.GetFolderFromPathAsync("Assets");
```

Q2 seems like you can use

[TryGetItemAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync.aspx)

Comment: The Directory class is not supported in a Windows Store project.

Comment: @user1954801 - I did a little bit of googling, if it doesnt work i'll delete my answer

Comment: thx, the second part of your answer is working for Windows Store projects. It is working for Assets but I can't figure out how to get the files from a subfolder of Assets. `... GetFolderFromPathAsync("Assets/Images");` is not working.

Comment: I would assume GetFolder().GetFolder() kind of thing would work, not too familiar sorry, my answer is based on google searches

Comment: Yep, it works. Thanks for your Input. I'll add my total solution (including file type search) in a separate answer (if that is ok) as I find that this answer is quite "sketchy".

Comment: @user1954801 - No worries, I agree it is sketchy but I have kept it here as it did provide a starting block